# How to populate Tkinter drop-down with Sqlite?

Tags: database, python-3.x, combobox, tkinter, listbox

How to populate Tkinter drop-down with Sqlite?

Here is what I have:

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3

root = Tk()
root.title('Testing Combobox, Listbox & Database')

db = sqlite3.connect('vehicles.db')
c = db.cursor()

# create Combobox
var = StringVar(root)
#var.set("") # initial value

# create Listbox
list = Listbox(root, width=50, height=20)

# Populate Listbox
query = c.execute('SELECT models FROM autos')
for i in query:
    listitems.insert(END,i)

# INSERT LISTBOX INTO COMBOBOX? HOW?
options = OptionMenu(root, var, xxxxxxx).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very. I am trying your suggestion, but now when I click on the arrow down, instead of seeing the data from the database, I am getting: .58088784. Before I was able to see the data but all in one line. (Note: just in case someone come across this thread, I see that on line 15 - create Listbox -  of my first example, "list" wasn't pasted as "listitems".)

Comment: Vijay, based on your suggestion I tried:

Comment: # create Listbox
    listitems = Listbox(root)

    # Populate Listbox
    query = c.execute('SELECT models FROM autos')

    for i in query:
        listitems.insert(END,i)

    list=ttk.Combobox(root, width=20, height=20)
    list['values']=listitems
    list.pack()

Comment: New to this site. Not finding how to show the codes correctly...

Comment: It worked with by replacing the "for loop" with "listitems = query.fetchall()" THANKS A LOT!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use a combo box

```
list=Combobox(root, width=50, height=20)
list['values']=listitems
list.pack()
```

this worked for me. 
Although for some reason I had to explicitly import ttk
that is

```
from tkinter import ttk
list=ttk.Combobox(root, width=50, height=20)
list['values']=listitems
list.pack()
```

Enter this code after you have completely populated your 'listitems',that is , after the 'for loop'

Answer (score 0):

Better yet (or the correct way) should be to remove the:

```
listitems = Listbox(root)
listitems = query.fetchall()
```

and replace:

```
list['values']=listitems
```

with

```
list['values']=query.fetchall()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the full working code. What's suggested by the OP in comments almost worked but the best I could do with that was a dropdown with values surrounded by curly brackets. Using code adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41880447/i-want-to-populate-a-ttk-combobox-with-results-from-database-query/), I arrived at this complete working code for what the OP was trying to do.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3

def create_table():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('vehicles.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS autos;") # use this line only if you want to overwrite existing table

    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS autos ('models' TEXT, 'year' DATE);")
    conn.commit()

    cur.execute("INSERT INTO autos VALUES ('Ford Falcon', 1965);")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO autos VALUES ('Chevy BelAir', 1954);")
    conn.commit()

    cur.close()
    conn.close()

def combo_values_input():

    conn = sqlite3.connect('vehicles.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()

    query = cur.execute('SELECT models FROM autos')

    data = []
    for row in cur.fetchall():
        data.append(row[0])
    return data

    cur.close()
    conn.close()

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Testing Tkinter Combobox with Sqlite')

create_table()

combo = ttk.Combobox(root, width=50, height=20)
combo.grid()
combo['values'] = combo_values_input()

root.mainloop()
```