# I want to populate a ttk.combobox with results from database query

Tags: sqlite, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

i am having a little problem i would need help with.This concerns python ttk.combobox widget
I am new to python just started coding a week ago.
I have a database which is populated by user input.This database is to store a user's stock input(e.g. items, cost, supplier ,etc).This part i have been able to do.

From the database, am using a 'for' loop to get each seperate item from my database query into a ttk.combobox so a user can make selections.
However my problem is,i get an error everytime.
I want the combobox to show all items within my item column from my database query.

From online sources ,i found out an example for ttk.combobox:

```
    list = ['shoe', 'toy', 'bag']
    combobox = ttk.Combobox(root)
    combobox['values'] = list
```

This works fine,if i am to use a self-made list
However , i can't find an example for a ttk.combobox using query from sqlite3 in python

Thank you in advance for helping me out with this problem.
An example of how to do it and an explanation of what i did wrong will help me alot.
Forgive me for my poorly organised coding style,i hope to get better at it as time goes on.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3

class Example:
    def __init__(self,master):
     self.master = master
     self.win_label = Label(master, text="New Stock Entry")
     self.win_label.grid(row=0, columnspan=2,)
     self.item_label = Label(master, text="Item Name", fg='black')
     self.item_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W, padx=5, pady=5)
     self.unitprice_lab = Label(master, text="Unit Price", fg='black')
     self.unitprice_lab.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W, padx=5, pady=5)
     self.total_price = Label(master, text="Total Price", fg='black')
     self.total_price.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W, padx=5, pady=5)
     self.quantity_lab = Label(master, text="Quantity", fg='black')
     self.quantity_lab.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W, padx=5, pady=5)
     self.manufacturer_lab = Label(master,text="Manufacturer", fg='black')
     self.manufacturer_lab.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=W, padx=5, pady=5)

      ############### Variables to store input ################
     self.item = StringVar()
     self.unitp = IntVar()
     self.unitn = IntVar()
     self.quantity = IntVar()
     self.man = StringVar()

     ############ Widgets############
     self.item_entry = Entry(master, width=25,textvariable=self.item)
     self.item_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
     self.unitprice_entry = Entry(master, width=25,textvariable=self.unitp)
     self.unitprice_entry.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W, padx=5, pady=5)
     self.total_price_entry = Entry(master,width=25,textvariable=self.unitn)
     self.total_price_entry.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, padx=5, pady=5)
     self.quantity_entry = Entry(master,width=25,textvariable=self.quantity)
     self.quantity_entry.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W, padx=5, pady=5)
     self.manufacturer_entry = Entry(master, width=25,textvariable=self.man)
     self.manufacturer_entry.grid(row=5, column=1, sticky=W, padx=5, pady=5)
     # button for save
     self.button_save = Button(master,text="Save",command= self.insert_Dbs)
     self.button_save.grid(row=6, column=1, pady=15, padx=10, sticky=W)

  def second_window(self):  # Second Window to allow user selection
    t = Toplevel()
    t.geometry('350x290')
    t.title('Student Input')

    ############# widgets ###############
    self.label1 = ttk.Label(t, text = 'Student Name')
    self.label1.grid(row =0 , column =0)
    self.label2 = ttk.Label(t, text='Item Collected')
    self.label2.grid(row=0, column=1)
    self.label3 = ttk.Label(t, text='Quantity')
    self.label3.grid(row=0, column=2)
    self.entry1 =ttk.Entry(t, width = 20)
    self.entry1.grid(row =1 , column =0)
    self.entry2 = ttk.Entry(t, width=20)
    self.entry2.grid(row=1, column=2)
    self.comb = ttk.Combobox(t,width = 15).grid(row =1 , column =1)
    self.comb['value'] = self.combo_input


  def insert_Dbs(self): # Function to insert input into database

    self.a1 = self.item.get()
    self.a2 = self.unitp.get()
    self.a3 = self.unitn.get()
    self.a4 = self.quantity.get()
    self.a5 = self.man.get()

    #db = sqlite3.connect('stockdbExample.db')
    '''db.execute('create table stocks (item text '
               ', item_uprice integer,'
               '  item_nprice integer,'
               ' quantity integer,'
               ' manufacturer text )')'''
    db = sqlite3.connect('stockdbExample.db')
    db.execute('insert into stocks (item,'
               ' item_uprice,'
               ' item_nprice,'
               ' quantity,'
               ' manufacturer) values (?, ?, ?, ?,?)',
               (self.a1, self.a2, self.a3, self.a4, self.a5))
    db.commit()
    self.combo_input()
    self.second_window()

  def combo_input(self):
    db = sqlite3.connect('stockdbExample.db')
    cursor = db.execute('select item from stocks')
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        return row

root = Tk()
c = Example(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: you have to `fetchall()` rows and manually create standard Python list which later you can use with `Combobox`

Comment: first rule: always put in question FULL error message - we can't read in you mind and we can't run you code to see this error. And put FULL message (Traceback) - there can me many usefull information - not only last text.

Comment: Thank you very much,am new here as well,i would definitely put your advice to good use in my subsequent questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: you forgot `()` to execute function

```
self.comb['value'] = self.combo_input()
```

Second: inside `combo_input` you use `return row` so you return only first row, nothing more.

You have to create Python list with all values and then return it.
It can be something like this:

```
def combo_input(self):
    db = sqlite3.connect('stockdbExample.db')
    cursor = db.execute('select item from stocks')

    result = []

    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        result.append(row[0])

    return result
```

---

**EDIT:** Full, working example:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import sqlite3

class Example:

  def __init__(self,master):
     self.master = master

     self.db = sqlite3.connect('stockdbExample.db')

     # use only once
     self.create_db()   

     self.cb = ttk.Combobox(master)
     self.cb.pack()
     self.cb['values'] = self.combo_input()

  def combo_input(self):
    cursor = self.db.cursor()

    cursor.execute('SELECT item FROM stocks')

    data = []

    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        data.append(row[0])

    return data

  def create_db(self):

    cursor = self.db.cursor()
    cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE stocks (item text)')
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO stocks (item) VALUES("Hello")')
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO stocks (item) VALUES("World")')
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO stocks (item) VALUES("Tkinter")')
    cursor.close()

    self.db.commit()

root = tk.Tk()
Example(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much ,i tried it and it works.Thank you once again.